# Correct behaviour if bound property cannot provide a value

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ListBox` that contains a large list of preview images. Images are downloaded from the internet and cached locally as the user scrolls over them. Therefor, the `AsyncPreview_120` binding is used which downloads the image and returns the path of the cached file. If this fails, a custom converter is used to generate a fallback image based on the filename.

```xml
<Image.Source>
  <PriorityBinding FallbackValue="{StaticResource DefaultImage}">
    <Binding Path="AsyncPreview_120" IsAsync="True" />
    <Binding Path="FileName" Converter="{StaticResource nameToImageSourceConverter}" IsAsync="True" />
  </PriorityBinding>
</Image.Source>
```

In some cases it might happen that downloading the preview fails, e.g. due to no internet connection. While this is working as expected, my question is what the Binding can return or throw, so that I do not get a warning or error from wpf.

I tried:

- Returning `null`
- Returning empty string
- Throwing `NotSupportedException`
- Returning `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`

but all resulted in errors or warnings. Is there any other way the binding could behave so that WPF treats this as some "legit" situation and silently moves on? Or is there maybe any better approach that I could use?

Comment: `Binding.DoNothing`

Comment: Do you really want to return an error. To my understanding, you could use the [`PriorityBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-prioritybinding) to wait in `AsyncPreview_120` until there is internet connection while showing the fallback image.

Comment: @Ackdari in that case, yes. But there are other situations where the preview does not exist on the server, so imho some kind of error would be needed there.

Comment: @JanGassen I think you should distigusish this kind of error inside `AsyncPreview_120` because you can only know that there is no image to show if you have connection to the server and use the second binding as an loading indicator or indicator for no connection

Comment: @Ackdari true, i'll give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Binding.DoNothing` 
[Binding.DoNothing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.donothing?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> A binding source property or a converter can return Binding.DoNothing
>   to instruct the binding engine not to perform any action. For example,
>   to instruct the binding engine not to transfer a value to the binding
>   target, not to move to the next Binding in a PriorityBinding, or not
>   to use the FallBackValue or default value.